# Restrict marker inside defined polygon in leaflet map

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I am using leaflet map for user tracking. I have a user marker and a polygon on map. Now i want that user marker remain inside defined polygon. And if user goes out from polygon then system alert him about this.
How can i achieve this functionality? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `booleanPointInPolygon` from turf.js https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon

```
var poly = L.polygon([[49,10],[48,20]]).addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([48.5,15]).addTo(map);

//Convert latlng to lnglat
var inPoly = booleanPointInPolygon(marker.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates,poly.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates)

console.log(inPoly);
```

PS: Not tested but should work.